# Export details of workflow from Informatica Powercenter Monitor

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse, informatica-powercenter, informatica

I am new to informatica. Whenever we run any workflow its details are shown in the monitor.
Everyday I need to prepare an excel report of those details manually.

I want to automate this process.

> For this job I wanted to know in which file details of the workflow run are stored which are displyed by Informatica monitor. So that I can build a program which will read that file interprete the values and will create an Excel report automatically avoiding my Manual work.

Modification - By details of Workflow I mean...

> 1. The number of records which were provided as input to interface.
> 2. The number of records which were successfully processed and sent to target table.
> 3. The number of records which were rejected during the process.
> 4. The number of records which went into Exception table.

Comment: @MarekGrzenkowicz: I have modified the post as you have asked.
Can you please help me for finding this information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repository database provides a set of views called Metadata Exchange (MX) Views that allow SQL access to the metadata. The information you need can be found in `REP_SESS_LOG` and `REP_SESS_TBL_LOG`. You will find a detailed description of these views in the *Repository Guide* - you can find it in the Informatica installation directory on your server or download from [Informatica My Support site](https://communities.informatica.com/) (you need to be a registered user).